# How I can Bind JSON key Starting with @symbol Using Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I am facing the following issue.
I am unable to bind a JSON key starting with `@` symbol.

Example:

```
var sampledata =
{
    "DataModel": {
        "Fields": [
            {
                "Format": null,
                "DisplayOrder": 0,
                "@defURI": "reporting.dashboard.TDataSetField",
                "DisplayName": "Firstname",
                "DefURI": "String",
                "Name": "firstname",
                "@nodeKey": 346316115241271300
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and my code is:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="fdata in fieldData.DataModel.Fields">
     <td>{{fdata.Name}}</td>
     <td>{{fdata.@defURI}}</td> <!-- this line is throwing an AngularJs error -->
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use **Bracket notation** like this

```
 <td>{{fdata['@defURI']}}</td>
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLWWqd)

Comment: Is there way to use it in ng-bind directive?

Comment: Yes try it as <div ng-bind="fdata['@defURI']"></div>

Comment: Hehe, thanks. That's great. I just forgot to delete dot when I tried with dot notation