# Angular JS not parsing nested JSON key with the at (@) in the key name

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am hitting an API which retrieves a nested JSON and setting it to my `$scope.data variable.`

I do an ng-repeat like `ng-repeat="event in data"`.
and try to access a value in the JSON `{{event.src.@userID.title}}`

There is an error
Lexer `Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 14-14 [@] in expression [event.src.@userID.title]`.

When I forcefully remove the @ from the JSON returned from the API and access as `{{event.src.userID.title}}` it works properly.

Please help so that I can access value with the @ in the key name.

The API that I hit returns a list [{"":""},{},{},{}] 
{"":""} is a nested list

Comment: is the key wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: yes, it is wrapped in double quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can Bind JSON key Starting with @symbol Using Angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775580/how-i-can-bind-json-key-starting-with-symbol-using-angular-js) - according to this answer, you need to use the bracket notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a different syntax to access an object property whose name isn't a valid variable name:

```
{{event.src["@userID"].title}}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks!